# Override CSS media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I work with a page every day that uses CSS media queries I don't like; I'd rather use the full page (most of them are related to the Twitter Bootstrap menu collapsing when narrower than 768px).

Is there a way to override Bootstrap's media queries with CSS? Preferably without defining my own media queries to override all of the rules individually, as I feel like this would take a pretty long time.

**Edit:** I don't have control of the source code, otherwise I'd just kill the bootstrap-responsive code.

Answer (score 11):

Why wouldn't you remove them in the first place?

If you can't, you still can override a CSS declaration with rules:

- that have the same selector priority and come **after** the MQ block
- that have **higher selector priority** than the rule in the MQ block
- that have **`!important`** between the value and the semi-colon

```css
    /* one id, one class AND one element => higher priority */
    #id element.class { property: value2; }

    /* !important will nuke priorities. Same side effects as a nuke,
       don't do that at home except if you've tried other methods */
    #id .class { property: value2 !important; }

    @media(blah) {
      /* Overridden. Thrice. */
      #id .class { property: value1; }
    }

    /* same selector, same everything except it comes after the one in @media?
       Then the latter is applied.
       Being in a @media doesn't give any more priority (but it won't be applied
       everywhere, depending on "blah", that's the point of MQ) */
    #id .class { property: value2; }
```

In the previous example, any of the declaration outside the `@media` block will override the one inside, e.g. there are 3 reasons why value2 will be applied and not value1.

Comment: I agree, if you don't like/need them, why not just remove the bootstrap-responsive.css file altogether?

Comment: I don't have control over the source.

Answer (score 2):

Would like to override bootstraps responsive.css too.

I have half of the website where I want to use the default responsive.css while for another half one media query causes wrong layouts so I want to remove it.

According to my research **css does not allow to remove a media query**.

So I will go and copy responsive.css and remove the media query. If you have no access to the source, overrides might be the only choice.

Comment: CSS doesn't allow to remove anything once written. You can only override an instruction (with a new value, in particular the default value of this property). If the instruction is in a rule that is in a Media Query, you can override it in every case or for this particular MQ by writing the exact same conditions for this MQ, same selector, same property and a new/default value (and place it after the instruction to be overriden)