# How to control the responsive navigation menu in the WordPress Twenty Twelve theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the default Twenty Twelve theme the top main menu changes to a button when the browser/screen width is less than 600px and functions differently. I have no idea what code controls or style this alternative menu.

[Twenty Twelve preview](http://wp-themes.com/twentytwelve/?TB_iframe=true&width=1149&height=527)

Can someone please help me find a way to disable/edit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've managed to figure out what controls this, I'm not sure if it answers my original question completely but I will share what I know now...

I believe it's mainly controlled by the media queries in the theme's style.css. In the section `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)` you will find styling for the navigation menu at screen/browser widths above 600px and once the width goes below 600px, the alternative styling is controlled by CSS declarations in the main body of the theme's CSS file, around line 578: `/* Navigation Menu */`.

The appearance of the button is also set in `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)` under the code `.menu-toggle {display: none;}` i.e. it is hidden above 600px and once the width goes below 600px, like before, it appears (no longer set to display:none) and uses the styling in the main body of the CSS file, around line 602.

So, if you want to disable the button altogether you can set it to `.menu-toggle {display: none !important;}` for ALL screen widths and if you want the appearance of your main navigation menu to stay fixed, make sure it is also styled for ALL screen widths, ensuring it overrides all of the menu styling under `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)`. You can override it by writing your code after the media query block. Useful answers on overriding CSS media queries can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425230/override-css-media-queries).

Answer (score 6):

This is handled by the /navigation.js  script ..

the line responsible for this is this :

```
<script src="http://wp-themes.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/navigation.js?ver=1.0" type="text/javascript">
```

you can disable that on line 103 at functions.php :

```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwelve-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '1.0', true );
```

Just comment it like so :

```
// wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwelve-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '1.0', true );
```

That being said, I do not really understand why would anyone want to disable this , But I guess that has nothing to do with the question ..

**Edit I :**

as @Lucky Son correctly commented , you should use [wp_deregister_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script)

```
wp_deregister_script( 'twentytwelve-navigation' )
```

Comment: Thanks Obmerk for directing me to the right place, now I know how to handle it in the future. I was just curious to know how it works as sometimes a menu can still be in clear view under w600px and there's no need for it to be changed in this way.

Comment: well, if this answer helped you, you might want to accept it as to mark it closed . as for the 600px issue , IMHO it is a bad idea to disable it , also because you can not control if a user use the tablet in landscape mode or other . and also not the tablet type.

Comment: isn't it a real headache... having to consider so many different screen sizes now!

Comment: you should use wp_deregister_script() to remove it.

Comment: If you want to remove the html as well, you should remove <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3> in the <nav> element in header.php

Answer (score 0):

Above solution did not work. This just seemed to prevent the menu button from functioning. What I am trying to do (and I assume as is the OP) is to prevent it from adding the ugly menu button and just use the same navigation as on desktop.

I only have three buttons on my site at the top, which would easily fit onto my mobile screen, instead I get a huge button which opens a huge dropdown. There is zero logic to this. Almost less logic than the Twenty Twelve theme putting the 'leave a reply' button at the top of the post by default. Stupid designers.

Comment: Hi, please see my own answer below. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me the easiest solution is to add min-width: 960px; in CSS so it wont resize the main body of site under 960px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .site {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 960px;
        min-width: 960px;                            --- THIS LINE ADDED
        max-width: 68.571428571rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

It may be prudent to apply a mobile plugin and disable the menu. Thereby allowing the user to select. I suppose it depends on the elements in the menu.